# Error creating spatial index in AZURE SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a spatial index on `geography`data type on Azure SQL. here is the code:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX IX_Shop_LatLong ON Shop(LatLong) 
USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID WITH (GRIDS = (LEVEL_1 = HIGH, LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM, LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM, LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, DROP_EXISTING = ON)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Could not find the spatial index 'IX_Shop_LatLong' on table 'Shop'. Either no spatial index with this name exists, or a non-spatial index might be using the same name. Fix the index name, avoiding duplicates. If a  relational index has the same name, drop the regular relational index.
```

I was trying giving other names but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is indicating that the spatial index definition doesn't exist for modification since you are using the DROP_EXISTING = ON option. With this option, a matching index (of correct type) needs to exist otherwise you will get this error. If you are creating the index from scratch on a table then you need to omit the DROP_EXISTING = ON option. You should think of CREATE INDEX WITH DROP_EXISTING = ON as an ALTER INDEX operation. It doesn't create the object itself. Hope this helps.